# 500 Internal Server Error on YouTube

Tags: youtube

I went to some channel on YouTube today and I found this error:

```
500 Internal Server Error

Sorry, something went wrong.

A team of highly trained monkeys has been dispatched to deal with this situation.

If you see them, show them this information:
T1hQ00IlOu6HEJIHFmF2IURDaz8DZkMPyk3G-ERtRIvuLdpamarzVNdBIpwh
lQj65SUNULlDhqVLGr6kza4z_nqGO_prIH7S6qmzkhNZyCcZmT84SYlQwJ0p
_iU9U-78rFPYJ837QcPGp2MaROxNwt7TGcAHcDJBPbusblOqpA0ls6y9m5xO
MS8llK53u0rUpnmbrz7-PdMiV1fkZYMTl3-niFIRAMM9FkI6zwhpTehM9pkT
Zzb_TuEF0bRkFyU0GALNM_vdePNg4_j9XUI5w8QmepK4WvpMGrqgKlOHsGdw
V9qJPtvWuube2lrp_5TTfe485vMlW-hui8sXcDiEYUcsbS8yt0-64ZyT3Yab
vvum6lQL0WNtihWzMWrRUZrX2SnSCzU1o5OMty-XdhkuIkby8m9fdhBX1nDs
X01H_5UkMInylI62O-qXMBy_W5mH9Htsq04p-1jV4IaZBCFvy6yHYN85Cs5_
gvE92PTCv6dsFkYqLMtm7Q-5Tzx3B00fPKUYep0i08ARUsgsNqPNFKxobLpm
1-uGs6uPndT-wK9pNdDVPaiavCk4Zy_EBsNS9tTOgB7opVNor1gvwm_KMnaz
jjdkxZB4vP3QgOL67au0kULhoQRpZ7DO_E0WL3Amy3r5fA3BqqWqWmFS65A9
BVXKr3vKj4JXiysUscypgaJGBN9M2cQ99nYKXohJ0wJv2K7cmhK6kHPjft07
P5IiE_TA8iUeaCNHB9a068-pgEb7PsZtk5FYhJv2IueLCmlwHUjvsWTAO6UM
SbGRaufDWAxIRyDnytiEVoxu8nSwJYMMSdaXxPGZ-ElF1n0xtlJIMldKRraa
NlgBSXtGUb0kER-6We_vUj1IdLYIjVtlLykKlOvPxA7lzmTKr9R4FiRgfjjw
y646VgznWNcLq8oGlFBdTMikd3ayexJSWgQJ6j3zyPsegHnwp-ibvnOGOZgB
X4wFZgdhyTyVWcywOHK16iil9_Xhf6m3C-1R476c2uUFZIdDr7jAfzwyIfz7
guund2L5N-Xdbwrd_ZyWWEVBGIy6iIsBoZiYeu8a2hRbc2YTNquOQ4WzRr6f
jJn1bXQwnkGbp1NX60nKZYDprTR4qq7hVa2ZzXgsPRDQfaz3df_VHpCrg86Q
9bvlpsk-B77lriUyU0Ivhrn7o5OzNZAWfLUqeO480tu5VCMK3GOXDdIQ5g6N
NoxiGd0QPQ1LI7VGBYLhS0sL7rs0LxODBdOt8AjiYNTxZEhI9eSuJJIIObyk
OMwy5Oot0dvFHJQSnZ43D6f6ygLhO9WNteeQiJP1C1MLSRfcJk8oFODbFKaN
Kti1dRZA5mnrkUJAG3FiEAhKoitMAoFlimr6MdyZERqH7HIZrTVRauJ7GJ3Q
QoG77Djxf3fyGVJDvmy-bTJ3oU-spOZgb_xLtPG7TzMpdDVWdND7-EA1NzLe
TIAUtQQKHnxZBXH6Dki54x2x-XGZmsq565NM42OPBABsyR4twQBllXD-Mij5
JIZBDQiiz1BCIPGc48TnM0aSR5GnwbJktY6WsV7wOzJE3YJ8HKIOFcoPGDLG
KW4374fIoFkukvJ5elY4PD8fWY1Ek6kw0-Cs-TBIAtWG47RxobGoqLR7JeVK
y5OaId4Ze7B86uYjRulNUJe-y0N5UhFiPS3Rhfr8mgOc5Y58YHVruZlCnrbU
jto7vKdaXl9-qImsUmI_sfamTaFJV7qz62MBajpZVOrTccRPKfJG5vAPv-0B
puX8-yy6HjYl7kKCRH3ka7STeuoOmEz4Ow4H_E8Cj3kuiIPN1XKcv2JXcH5M
nPb15ijdusseNuSxVf1AjlpQVpO02wc_x6t3wLxPKyua1NgIRGpm3LfYLHEt
uTlOayR58EQFkzNBzkxi_bqUgK2MQKQUJS6BMY_-wdfuFRHjGct5W0lD7Gm3
BZIcY_GXdwYLJ0hr2S1Ezmg5-w4TpG8n8VZny7uJ359Gt55ZQSkqfR9qdJRP
6gTEVmbQYqiEpU8qgyNy_6wPqmHUGdM4ZUSNBRxIQ84gCB3raf7s5aac72BV
Q8KZfj71Ri0YDjG2RFabbY5WPAn5Weari3vgl0IO8XIoxdDNwEvWmnIFuK_f
Z4mdM3C_dN_QbTZj8Wk0yaTYgL1_1xgg9-nTpTxlNbNgh5SUaDnbxQNnPaV3
hmFhg_vC-8_Ncv2RrKTyWd9N1FK8RJ1w9KMFXlbOV5yJ6-556AusiJauQPAZ
1c89TlLSblEheeNGAFDGTECVhIxcoVMiy-j4iwPuSy71wII42O313J-c6Ecp
YLDQkAePhaLf3MMWPZt5b_FbppvgCH1fqBKaApBAHwAbGvT6pBPMfvwBsCnw
Esj6c_rsCmfWKVqrudnbi07Au2h84z11Hzug1fRDWKFLp0wOjAKGGiIfsubB
QXqzOEgZFsNe9NNNk6rLFGuYn9qZuYZS2HmiJZQHP0M9gE9S4IhySxzJ8SZz
h0tCHczv6xaqJn4KjafD-XlV0J035gQ940sXxJo6nGi48R4TVFww4FVCHjNm
m2EVwbwTE1iuinC_n8feNfdERuXWY5sWGjb6rOPdBFsBocnSq92hAVR3BBLN
kGG0fKSSSphP-omOuqC4ZNq24FiGyo9TLZk2-At-SQn44zuNSdTpZE2iwsPn
QYEoOj-ktCkjtuexnSUfvp-OVnO3HbtDOSN1M0dsp8FXJTfpGmj5IW1lECHt
3lOWDrn5qByhWVdZHu1Gtj2zZhGfZ86VAJX6FROhXuF4ihWwnz8YiAg2P9wM
ZdgX7MDRyzHtw8xNfeMG1Oo85IAAv2VBdVYFe_jMIP-MPmiLjGJ3vVbWDWh3
SN2XT9qDifV34GzTefKuRL86ZzTxf20Z0ZnORzkDSQB28EnMgpB54EXa6XhC
AUx42Rl777i5O7n3VRo1QfgFsVpu_mLlggLvcxogrgzRvI4mx5je_suidWp3
69CokIHAdvzqJcdRY9YLem8MIFTaTfAIlf9Ldp4_1Ue3i8LwNmEFFWcjiQPF
ZIJxy41KD6iD1VxsvzkLev90Ac08GsO9abt1gRuTsmclS_dGKCVQ3N2c648L
sslnpFTl6XTt7d7-5Jl5uU-Gu9dIZrRxid3rBqtgIB7gAXg2u7KwY8j48dl1
UeQpSiqUT8xaFnVSvHnEKWcdcpQZNVDzWN4wDREeDeihCOIpA9pvhezqw-rs
kbFhLx4ZyJBzTxvtcLHupkt51Paspiq_Qtct0f8NCz8oSJlzorBg3CXuF3zp
MyxtHN0hEWZH--jWeEV4xmCUIphk0SOIIuTE0Ge7tBwp-AzzoJLGLgBCCTQx
vlHIj6C033DQ2r-XtcofT73dLWWa9_gUrmPDw7MhA8X2uoL0TWJv9tBdtMjZ
opxbCm9W9mzJWX0k_W6hlsb5fIJNcwI7SNITGdVfjt9e0QKBlRPnLxwcMvUv
dQpZG2w_noL8L-T28mVzPNjO7PNSXxIc7W4RdQp7uZo2b-30HYTqvLZAey3z
3_iq6TCQVnoWZ7U2F_9jeQYrpBGjQusnHyM3xcaPtJZrSGTjms_cayhc7C8S
KzV6MjcLK5eqs3IwuU3OTAdisVejE4gvmDDiXImISvg1MV1BioBmW1tA_Fwd
kdNYu4eDF145Jh8kfL1d-adepWXLX7vOY_-wt_2F102Ey_yU321JzD37O3fA
m2QiBpbFgfm0HyZ_zjIYJEgF0NFWS_ql0cX0Xdd9KhZhGxyHvtUgcq6AAUCZ
C5dTS46lK6oeL_calb0-Zjk2q__1qMaArUWmo7CmaRUHmcRIN4prpfAhdGC8
JmnzoyIVZsFK1eTHMMPfzGatWZ-odIhScZR8OjssODs6H6931waTmw9azHqz
MwcwmF2d15MHiLMHpJEZ6Ve7JRCQ81VfaEL1MkRObZBu_lWEC_YwTtDpaZfD
x6ktT3fgk0lTilt0PJ5irrKS7zhZKafnASuhgFmsptEoqRZHLElnqKlJOVna
8Vl9Q9-slTR6GxKDhA1jhD2OEoAF_g==
```

Indeed, it's a 500 error. I googled it and seems to be a joke, but I'm curious about the information that is displayed. What does it mean?

Comment: A joke?! I don't get it. ;) A 500 "Internal Server Error" is a very real error (if that is what is actually being returned) - although it is a "generic" error, when the server is not able to respond with another, more meaningful, error! By itself, a 500 error does not really help in solving the problem, other than there was "an error". The data dump is likely to hold more clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.cambus.net/decoding-youtube-http-error-500-message/:

> The information is encoded in modified base64 for URL applications
>   (base64url encoding), which differs from original base64 by the fact
>   that the padding character ‘=’ is dismissed and the ‘+’ and ‘/’
>   characters gets respectively replaced by ‘-’ and ‘_’ characters.

However, as underlined in the comments, the base64 data is very likely encrypted:

> The base64 data is very likely encrypted, and only Google, Inc. has the decryption key. It's useful to them if you send the base64 junk, but you can't get any details about their server through that error.

and:

> gzip -9 increases the size ever so slightly. Lends more credence to it being encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

500 is the HTTP code for `Internal Server Error` . This means that some error happened at YouTube's end, sites often put up funny messages when some error occur so that you derive some laughter from what could be an irritable situation.
You cannot really do anything about it and in this case the message doesnt really contain anything jsut like Franck mentioned.
You can look up HTTP Error codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error).